# WebRTC record div contains local and remote stream

Tags: webrtc, simplewebrtc, openwebrtc, rtcpeerconnection, rtcmulticonnection

I want to record a video stream with the same style CSS in HTML, in which local video in the bottom left of remote video it's possible to do this?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: I want to record stream with append style

Comment: what do you mean by append style?